# Parallel computing in image processing?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, parallel-processing, gpu

Can anybody give me some examples and brief explanation of parallel computing in image processing (that could make use of CUDA kernels on an Nvdia GPU) ? For example with regards to pixels my perception so far is that the image could be split into smaller sections and same process applied to those sections to build the overall objective, but is there more to it than that? Also how would that be achieved in terms of programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this : http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/intro-to-image-processing-with-cuda/

The linked page contains direct answers to your questions, and example code for a quick start.